# Optimizing Calculation in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a three models, Property, Visit, and Session. I need to calculate the average session time for a property, and so far I have the following methods:

In my Session model:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :visits

  def session_duration
    visits.last.created_at - visits.first.created_at
  end

end
```

And then in my Property model:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :visits
  has_many :sessions

  def avg_session_duration
    @sessions = Session.where(property_id: self.id)

    (@sessions.collect(&:session_duration).sum/@sessions.length)/60 if   @sessions.length > 0
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I run `avg_session_duration` on a property with thousands of sessions the calculation takes far too long, in the order of minutes. I know there must be a more efficient way to do this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Denormalization is also worth looking into. Meaning, you should have first and last visits dates in the session row. When another visit added, update the last session cached time. This way, you'll have to query only sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this happens because of the [*N+1 queries problem*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations): your are querying `visits` for each item in the `@sessions` collection. Try with [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes):

```
@sessions = Session.includes(:visits).where(property_id: self.id)
```

Comment: I believe it'll be even a single query, with a JOIN, no?

Comment: Thanks, using includes was much better than what I had!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Actually, when I run `includes` in my project with `has_many` association ActiveRecord builds two queries..Docs say that using `includes` may _often_ result in using a `join`, but in my humble experience things went this way only when I was forcing it with `references` or referenced conditions for associated table in the `where` method.